# Batch adding managedObjects to Core Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

The following shows a method that I have added to a subclass of NSManagedObject to populate and add individual entities to Core Data. I have about a 1000 objects to add to the data base (which I am doing in a loop, not a list as shown below) My question is with regards to performance, does adding each of the 1000 objects 1 by one add a significant overhead to the Core Data (I would assume it does). Is there a way to store each of the managed objects and them add them in a single (faster) way.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self managedDocument] managedObjectContext];
[Atomal createAtomalInContext:context withName:@"H11" age:@57 andType:@"Nantar"];
[Atomal createAtomalInContext:context withName:@"H23" age:@22 andType:@"Nantar"];
[Atomal createAtomalInContext:context withName:@"H54" age:@11 andType:@"Nantar"];
[Atomal createAtomalInContext:context withName:@"H34" age:@98 andType:@"Nantar"];
[Atomal createAtomalInContext:context withName:@"H17" age:@35 andType:@"Nantar"];
```

.

```
+ (Atomal *)createAtomalInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context withName:(NSString *)name age:(NSNumber *)age andType:(NSString *)type {
    Atomal *atomal = nil;
    atomal = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Atomal" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // POPULATE PROPERTIES
    [atomal setName:name];
    [atomal setAge:age];
    [atomal setType:type];
    NSLog(@"CORE: Adding >>> %@ %@ %@", [atomal name], [atomal age], [atomal type]);
    return atomal;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fine. If you are really worried about performance and you are actually having issues with your implementation then you should profile and get real results to work on instead of just asking for opinions.

In saying that this should be fairly inexpensive as all of the managed object are created in memory - it will be when you call `save:` that Core Data starts to hit the disk. The IO of hitting the disk is the slow part so if you make sure you keep that to a minimum you should be fine.

Again one of the more expensive things you are doing here is logging, which is IO outputting  to a log, you can really notice this effect if you do a lot of logging in a tight loop.

Comment: Hi Paul, I was just curious as I am at this stage only planning out how I am going to do things, just making notes and trying to work out the best way to set things up (hence my lack of anything to profile). Your advice is much appreciated.

Comment: With the xcode templates and your code you wouldn't be far off mocking up something to get yourself some real numbers (and peace of mind that things will work). I'd consider making a quick prototype just for the practice...

Comment: It's also worth experimenting with how often you save. I've found that one big save at the end can be problematic, so in those cases I've used a simple counter and performed a save after every n objects I created.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was aware of the logging, but thats certainly a good one to mention, I am in the process of building a prototype now but have not gotten round to looking at performance, I was just trying to make sure that my initial pitch was on the right (-sh) track for now. Also thanks ChrisH for the saving comment, I will certainly look into that. Have a good weekend everyone, thanks again ...